# Unity3D Android build report complete size too large

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, report

I noticed the complete size takes up to 90% more than it should in my Android project. What are the things that takes so much of space? I read some topics in this forum and some claimed it's the unity engine that has big size, but for ~130MB!? How do we check wat takes up so much space?

```
Build Report
Uncompressed usage by category:
Textures      7.7 mb     5.3% 
Meshes        735.3 kb   0.5% 
Animations    779.7 kb   0.5% 
Sounds        0.0 kb     0.0% 
Shaders       69.1 kb    0.0% 
Other Assets  125.9 kb   0.1% 
Levels        29.1 kb    0.0% 
Scripts       1.1 mb     0.8% 
Included DLLs 3.9 mb     2.7% 
File headers  44.6 kb    0.0% 
Complete size 145.3 mb   100.0%
```

**Edit:**
This is what i got from analysing the APK using Android Studio, and it seems smaller from unity report. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check your apk file like this:
Android Studio -> Build -> Analyze APK

[image]

Comment: I checked and it seems like it's using unity engine lib for x86 and armv7, with 2 separate .so files. Both adds up till 50MB. I manage to reduce half by splitting the APK. But still, why it shows 145.3 MB while it's not taking tat much @Liar

Comment: Can you give a screenshot? @kkl

Comment: Is my answer enough for your question "How do we check wat takes up so much space?"?

Comment: Hi @Liar, I edited my post to attach a screenshot. I wanted to know why the unity3D reports ~140MB but it's just so much smaller in APK. Can proguard really shrink the APK to tat much?

Comment: When you install apk, does it work as expected? If it works well, maybe some resources in your project are ignored during building apk @kkl

Comment: yes no error or crash. My question is, why unity3D report shows the complete size so big while it does not show what's taking that much since all adds up does not match the total size in that report